# How To Get Current Location With Pop Up Box Using Mapbox

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to get current location (latitude and longitude) with mapbox likes vanilla javascript do ? What i want is like image number one, but i think using the vanilla javascript location makes the location not accurate, and i want to using the mapbox but it's only provides using the button which must showing the map first.

[image: Image number one, using vanilla javascript to get latitude and longitude]

[image: Image number two, using mapbox but the user must click the button first]

So, what i want is how can i get user current location (latitude and longitude) when the page is loaded or when the user click a button without showing the map on mapbox.

Comment: You cannot and it is unethical.  What you are doing with JavaScript is just get the public IP geo information.

Answer (score 0):

The Mapbox example you referenced is using [Mapbox' GeoLocate Control](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#geolocatecontrol), which in turn is utilizing the browsers [Geolocation API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) to determine the current position.

Therefore, there is no advantage in using the Geolocate Control of Mapbox, if you do not want to display the returned position on a Mapbox map.

Example how to get geolocation in HTML page:

```js
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```